# Intellij Idea 13 jsf using Tomcat.. ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying basic jsf example with IntelliJ IDEA 13 but I have a problem:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Is your servlet instantiated in your faces-config.xml?

Comment: my faces-config.xml file is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, copy jars

**jsp-api.jar ,
jstl-1.1.0.jar**

to apache tomcat/lib folder.